# Node js: sendgrid 'acces forbidden'

Tags: node.js, npm, sendgrid

I'm using sendgrid (javascript) to add a new contact to my list.
Within marketing.

```
var request = require("request");

  var options = { method: 'PUT',
    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/193029b7-0b8b-4c0c-948d-47d09a157542/recipients',
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer myapi' },
    body: '{"contacts":[{"email": "myemail@gmail.com","unique_name":"hello"}]}' };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
  });
```

But then I get the message 'acces forbidden'.

Am I using the wrong url?
(The API token is set to administrator all access.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a few things going on here.

According to the [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html), there are not endpoints in the Contact API that accept the method `PUT`.

After checking our own implementation, it also looks like there's an issue with what you're intending to do.

See the [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Multiple-Recipients-to-a-List-POST) for adding multiple recipients to a list:

```
POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients HTTP/1.1

Request body:
[
  "recipient_id1",
  "recipient_id2"
]
```

In order to use that method, you need to first [create](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Multiple-Recipients-POST) the users and retrieve their recipient ID's.

```
POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients HTTP/1.1
[
  {
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "unique_name":"hello"
  }
]
```

Check out the links posted for more information on their usage and response.